# fazer retorno de consulta SQL de forma organizada

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho a seguinte tabela SQL:

```
|`id` | `user_id` | `key` | `value` |
|------------------------------------
| 1   |    1      |  nome | João da silva, 50
| 2   |    1      |  docs | 552.282.820-58, 22.532.25, 1.230.253-15
| 3   |    1      |  cep  | 0852-364, 15685-225
| 4   |    2      |  nome | Lais dos Santos, 19
| 5   |    2      |  docs | 255.365.358-74, 24.582.659, 4.526.874-9
| 6   |    3      |  nome | Thais Paula dos Santos, 40, promotora
| 7   |    3      |  docs | 258.481+574-85, 14.582.478, 3.546.874-8
| 8   |    3      |  cep  | 05832-005, 04185-007
| 9   |    3      |  ende | João Pessoa, 1040, Vila Almeida
```

**Estou tentando fazer um select mas não estou conseguindo que retorne os valores referente a coluna key e value, de forma organizada conforme a tabela abaixo:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       nome            |               docs                      |          cep        |            ende
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
João da silva           | 552.282.820-58, 22.532.25, 1.230.253-15 | 0852-364, 15685-225 | 
Lais dos Santos         | 255.365.358-74, 24.582.659, 4.526.874-9 |                     |
Thais Paula dos Santos  | 258.481+574-85, 14.582.478, 3.546.874-8 | 05832-005, 04185-007|João Pessoa, 1040, Vila Almeida
```

**meu select esta desta forma:**

```
$resultado = $pdo->select("SELECT * FROM bd");

foreach ($resultado as $res) {
    $msg .="                ";
    $msg .="                    ".$res['id']."";
    $msg .="                    ".$res['user_id']."";
    $msg .="                    ".$res['key']."";
    $msg .="                    ".$res['value']."";
    $msg .="                ";
}

echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, você está tentando armazenar e exibir os dados resultantes da consulta em forma de String.
Acho que o ideal seria você armazenar e exibir em forma de Array pra ficar mais organizado tanto para você manipular os dados depois quanto para você visualizá-los de forma mais organizada.

Vou postar os dois jeitos pra você. Da forma que você pediu na pergunta e em forma de Array.

**String**

```
$resultado = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM bd");

$msg = ""; 
foreach ($resultado as $res) {

    $msg .= $res['id']." | ";
    $msg .= $res['user_id']." | ";
    $msg .= $res['key']." | ";
    $msg .= $res['value']." | ";
    $msg .= "<br>";     
}

echo $msg;
```

**Array**

```
$resultado = $pdo->query("SELECT id, user_id, key, value FROM bd");
$resultado = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$msg = array(); 

foreach ($resultado as $res) {

    $msg[] = $res;          
}

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($msg);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: talvez não tenha explicado corretamente, mas observer que a coluna key, ela armazena os nomes referente as colunas, e se vc observar vai notar que a coluna user_id, o nome irá se repetir de acordo com o id cliente, e a coluna value armazena os dados ou valores. para talvez facilitar o esclarecimento, foque na coluna user_id, key e value, e observe a segunda tabelinha lá da minha pergunta, para ver como o resultado do select deveria vir, não é a formatação que quero, mas sim o cabeçalho e o corpo.

Comment: Brother, você tentou rodar o código que postei ? O que saiu ? Logicamente você deve alterar o nome dos campos da consulta e adaptar algumas coisas conforme a sua necessidade. A minha resposta foi só um modo de você realizar a consulta e exibir os dados.

Comment: entendi... o problema é que estou penando justamente ao trazer estes resultados para php e exibir, não consigo fazer dar certo!

Comment: Quando você executou os dois códigos que eu postei, quais foram as saídas que deram no seu arquivo ? Deu algum erro ou algo do tipo ? Acrescente mais informações.

Comment: os dois rodaram de boa, o primeiro ficou no formato da tabela que enviei, mas o grande x da questão pra mim é a ordenação mesmo, o cabeçalho tem que ser nome            |               docs                      |          cep        |            ende , e as colunas os dados da coluna value, entendeu?